# Better solutions for a Database Access Layer than my .NET assembly solution?

Tags: c#, .net, data-access-layer

For an upcoming effort I'll be looking at a partial rewrite of an existing system.  One piece of it is a DAL which is implemented as a .NET assembly that is referenced by a few applications and provides methods to push things to an underlying DB and retrieve data from that DB.  Essentially, I provide the users of the DLL with a means to connect to some DB and make a limited set of calls to it.  Rather than the users writing SQL themselves, they use my defined interface.

Now there have been discussions about using some data access service layer instead of the existing DLL and the cited benefits by the proponents of this approach are that it is "maintainable", "testable", "scaleable" - all the standard buzzwords.  There was also claims that this approach somehow minimizes the impact on the applications using the layer because it isolates the changes, though I'm not convinced this is the case.  It would seem to me that any layer between the underlying DB and the application is going to have a well-defined interface and so changes made on either side which don't involve the other side of the interface will be invisible and have no real impact.  Too, any changes which *do* affect the other side would may require changes to that middle layer as well.  I don't see how it wouldn't.

It's expected that early on changes will be required to the DAL because, well, stuff changes.  Method parameters change and it causes me currently to recompile the DAL assembly and distribute it to the users of the DAL.  These don't happen too often but they do.  I may be a bit naive in this area but I'm not aware of a better way to get the applications out of the DB-interfacing business than what I currently have in place.  Does anyone have specific knowledge about DAL solutions which provide for better modularity?  I've read a few posts here and elsewhere on the net but none really talking about this.  If there's an existing question that addresses this already, I'd be interested in seeing a link to this and would be happy to close this question.

---

**Additional info:**

A shorter version of my long question above is "What would be an advantage of *not* using the DLL approach that I currently employ?"  The current model I employ has the following characteristics:

- A number of POCO classes which abstract the underlying DB model (these classes are not currently auto-generated but were hand-built, though I guess they could be auto-generated via EF or something like that though I'm not sure it really matters)
- A number of public methods which can be called, e.g., `GetOrderDetails(int orderID)` or `SubmitOrder(Order newOrder)`
- It handles the DB connection string via inputs which are provided by the app using the DLL

Comment: A couple questions:  How would the data access service layer be different?  Would that be like using Linq2Sql and the users would write queries in that instead of using your functions?   I'd think that your DLL would be as easy if not easier to build test cases for than any other implementation...

Comment: @Thymine - there was talk about something like WCF Data Services being used - well, specifically it was mentioned that OData was involved and I gathered that WCF Data Services is what they were considering.  I haven't spent nearly enough time looking at this but from my 5 second tour of it, I'm not convinced it's any better, unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: If the interface for your data access layer is so well defined (which is a great thing), surely consumers of it shouldn't know or care how it's implemented? It could be an ORM, message queue or WCF data services as you mention, as long as all of those implementations satisfy the DAL contract, no one needs to know! It's the principle of protected variation :)

Comment: @MattDavey - Thanks for the comment.  It seems the proponents of a new/different DAL layer believe that a different implementation would somehow isolate the changes, which I'm not sure I get quite frankly.  When things change in a DB, for instance, which result in new/different things being available to consumers/producers of that data, those changes would necessarily have to ripple outward regardless of the DAL employed, unless there's some solution that I don't know about.

Comment: @itsmatt I guess it's a matter of viewpoint. In my opinion the DAL interface/contract is the specification, DAL implementations work towards implementing it, and the domain/application layer consumes it. Any new data access requirements should be added to the DAL interface *first*, immediately invalidating previous DAL implementations such that hey have to implement new features. In essence it's the interface that drives changes in the DB, not the other way 'round...

Comment: @MattDavey - sure, totally get and agree with what you are saying. We're talking about an interface here so if my DB person adds an index on a table or changes some sproc to more efficiently do X or Y, I couldn't care less as long as the contract hasn't changed.  But if I need to get Orders or some other piece of information not supplied by the DAL, then it'll change and possibly the underlying DB will too, depending upon how retrieval happens.  Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion not knowing any of the details, assuming smaller project with not too many clients, I'd say stick with the dll, and make sure the latest version of that is on a fileshare or at a url that can be downloaded by a script, preferably the build process automatically.

Ah, wasn't exactly sure what you meant by data access service layer.
I think giving good feedback on this we'd need to know how many clients, types of clients, what kind of methods would be in it (i think huge select queries of complex objects would be a poor fit for WCF or similar).  Also since WCF is so versatile, would this be on the same machine, over a LAN, over the internet?

I've used WCF slightly, but not in that context really.

It might be slightly more modular than your DLL as long as all the changes you make do not break the contract (only adding new methods) but I'd say the big benefit would come if you needed it accessed from different platforms, or enough clients that database connections would be strained.
Some errors with WCF can be difficult to debug.  And if you do have to break the contract you have to send them a new servicecontract.cs file for that still

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of your question and the client's desire, I believe they are talking about something along the lines of SOA or Service Oriented Architecture. According to the SOA principle it does allow for a modular and loosely coupled approach. This can lead to easier maintenance in that the logic of the data access routine can be altered, updated and/or maintained without affecting the clients.  Also, say, you have twenty clients that make use of the "service" - there will be no need to update and deploy a new dll to all of the clients that make use of the "service" or DAL.

In terms of the platform or technology used to implement SOA systems, it could be whatever you chose. Or more accurately, whatever is the right tool for the job. You could roll your own, you could use WCF or you could also make use of WebAPI... etc...

Here are some links on the topic:

[Introduction to SOA - JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2005/jw-0613-soa.html)

[Service Oriented Architecture with .NET](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/article.php/c19627/Realizing-a-ServiceOriented-Architecture-with-NET.htm)

[Service Oriented Architecture and Microsoft .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/john_charles/Service_Oriented_Architecture_and_Microsoft_NET01202006080616AM/Service_Oriented_Architecture_and_Microsoft_NET.aspx)

[MS Architecture Journal #21 - SOA Today and Past](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/aa699437)

[Understanding Service Oriented Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480021.aspx)

Comment: after all that I just realized this question was over a year old. :/